# Cross Product of a Vector

Tags: calculus

[image]

Hey everyone, for this problem I'm confused as to what you do to get what $2w \times w$ is. I understand that you have to distribute the $w$ on the outside and you get $2u \times w +2w^2$ but I'm confused as to how I'm supposed to derive what w even is. Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|\vec u \times\vec w |=
||\vec u|\vec w|\sin \theta|$

Hence, $2\vec w\times\vec w=\vec 0$

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm having a little trouble of grasping why 2w x w is zero, but correct me if I'm wrong, I think it's because if you draw the vector 2w x w the angle between the two vectors is 0? or is my reasoning incorrect?

Comment: @Shenuque That's correct. Good work. Cross product of parallel vectors is $\vec 0$

Comment: Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Shenuque Note that cross product represents area of parallelogram formed by two adjacent sides as the vectors. If they are parallel, no parallelogram can be formed and the area is $\vec 0$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The absolute value of the cross product of vectors $a, b$ is $|a||b|\sin\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors. What does this tell you about $2w \times w$?

Answer (score 0):

Use these:

$c(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y})=c\mathbf{x}+c\mathbf{y}$

$c\mathbf{x}\times\mathbf{y}=c(\mathbf{x}\times\mathbf{y})$

$\|\mathbf{x}\times\mathbf{y}\|=\|\mathbf{x}\|\,\|\mathbf{y}\|\sin\theta$

where $c$ is a scalar and $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}$ are vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Cross product is distributive over addition.

$(2u+2w) \times w=2u \times w + 2 w \times w=2u \times w = (8,6,-4).$